# Go log file swapper

Tags: go, logging

Please review my code. I left some comments where I think something might be wrong, but any comment is appreciated.

I am writing a package for a project I am currently building. Its purpose is simply to swap from one log file to another after some time has elapsed. It zips the log before creating a new one and if there are any .log files that are not zipped before running the program it zips them all. I use a timer that sends a signal when the countdown finishes and then it is reset.

The Swapper

```go
package swapper

import (
    "api/logs/archiver"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

type output struct {
    directory string
    logFile   *os.File
}

type Swapper struct {
    swapCountdown time.Duration
    mutex         sync.Mutex
    logger        *log.Logger
    output        output
}

func NewSwapper(swapCountdown time.Duration, logger *log.Logger) *Swapper {
    newSwapper := new(Swapper)

    newSwapper.swapCountdown = swapCountdown
    newSwapper.logger = logger

    return newSwapper
}

func (swapper *Swapper) SetOutput(directory string) error {
    swapper.output.directory = directory

    err := archiver.ZipAll(directory)

    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    err = swapper.createFile()

    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    swapper.chooseLogger()

    return nil
}

func (swapper *Swapper) createFile() error {
    filename := fmt.Sprintf("%s/api_%s.log", swapper.output.directory, time.Now().Format("2006-01-02T15-04-05"))

    logFile, err := os.OpenFile(filename, os.O_CREATE|os.O_RDWR, 0666)

    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    swapper.output.logFile = logFile

    return nil
}

func (swapper *Swapper) swapFile() error {
    swapper.mutex.Lock()
    defer swapper.mutex.Unlock()

    err := swapper.output.logFile.Close()

    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    err = archiver.ZipOne(swapper.output.logFile.Name())

    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    err = swapper.createFile()

    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    swapper.chooseLogger()

    return nil
}

func (swapper *Swapper) ScheduleNextSwap() error {
    timer := time.NewTimer(swapper.swapCountdown)

    for {
        select {
        case <-timer.C:
            err := swapper.swapFile()

            if err != nil {
                return err
            }

            timer.Reset(swapper.swapCountdown)
        default:
            // for testing purposes ...
            time.Sleep(2 * time.Second)

            log.Println("logging...")
        }
    }
}

func (swapper *Swapper) Close() error {
    err := swapper.output.logFile.Close()

    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    return nil
}

func (swapper *Swapper) chooseLogger() {
    if swapper.logger == nil {
        log.SetOutput(swapper.output.logFile)
    } else {
        swapper.logger.SetOutput(swapper.output.logFile)
    }
}
```

The Archiver

```go
package archiver

import (
    "archive/zip"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "io/fs"
    "os"
    "path/filepath"
    "strings"
)

func ZipAll(directory string) error {
    err := filepath.Walk(directory, func(path string, info fs.FileInfo, err error) error {
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }

        if info.IsDir() == false && strings.HasSuffix(info.Name(), ".log") {
            err = ZipOne(path)

            if err != nil {
                return err
            }
        }

        return nil
    })

    return err
}

func ZipOne(logFilepath string) error {
    zipFilename := strings.TrimSuffix(logFilepath, ".log")

    zipFile, err := os.Create(fmt.Sprintf("%s.zip", zipFilename))

    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    defer func(zipFile *os.File) {
        // error is not handled because log file is closed and the app is deployed as service so no fmt.Println()
        _ = zipFile.Close()
    }(zipFile)

    file, err := os.Open(logFilepath)

    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    zipWriter := zip.NewWriter(zipFile)

    defer func(zipWriter *zip.Writer) {
        // error is not handled because log file is closed and the app is deployed as service so no fmt.Println()
        _ = zipWriter.Close()
    }(zipWriter)

    fileInfo, err := file.Stat()

    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    header, err := zip.FileInfoHeader(fileInfo)

    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    writer, err := zipWriter.CreateHeader(header)

    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    _, err = io.Copy(writer, file)

    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    err = os.Remove(logFilepath)

    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    return nil
}
```

Example of how to use it:

```go
package main

import (
    "api/logs/swapper"
    "os"
    "os/signal"
    "time"
)

func main() {
   newSwapper := swapper.NewSwapper(5*time.Second, nil)

   err := newSwapper.SetOutput("/A PATH TO LOGS FOLDER/logs")

   if err != nil {
       panic(err)
   }

   go func() {
     err = newSwapper.ScheduleNextSwap()

      // panics if an error occurred when swapping the file which might exit the app in production env if an error is raised.
      if err != nil {
          panic(err)
      }
   }()

   defer func(swapper *swapper.Swapper) {
      err = newSwapper.Close()

      if err != nil {
          panic(err)
      }
   }(newSwapper)

   interruptSignal := make(chan os.Signal, 1)

   signal.Notify(interruptSignal, os.Interrupt)

   <-interruptSignal
}
```